# Append an object without its associated objects

Tags: objects, linked-data, append

When I append an object, it also appends a lot of other associated objects, such as it's rig, and even the rig's custom shapes. And if I append an armature object (not just the data), then i also get all of the objects that use it, and even other rigs on those objects and their custom shapes. This makes for a massive cleanup job any time I want to grab even a simple accessory from a previous project.

Is it possible to link an object without getting it's associates? I am aware that I can link only the object or armature data, which avoids this problem, but then I lose my modifiers, constraints, etc.

Comment: Have you tried unticking the *Localize All* option in the file browser settings (bottom left)?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that does it! Want to put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While apending, in the file browser, untick the option *Localize All* at the bottom left settings panel.