# How do I recover my corrupted blender file through reverse engineering?

Tags: error, blend-files, source-code

The only thing that crashed is blender, and my C drive keeps running out of space. The crash was caused by adding a remesh modifier after a subdivision modifier. I saved the backup file that saved my work a few minutes before that. How I reverse engineer the project file to retrieve and recode (fix) my corrupted mesh?

Comment: perhaps this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/append-an-object-without-its-associated-objects

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: I'm afraid that the best you are going to be able to do open some file, and then try FIle -> Recover -> Auto Save to see if the last autosave is recent enough to be useful.  Sometimes you can try Last Session instead.

Comment: I'll add that in Windows, blender keeps autosaves in `../AppData/Local/Temp`. Autosave files end in .autosave (obviously). Try sorting by most recently modified to try and get the most recent one.